# J2ME store image to file

Tags: image, java-me, storage

I'm trying to create a program that emulates the camera. How can I store the Image to a file in the mobile? I am targeting Symbian S60v3, using Nokia N82 for my test mobile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nevermind, I got it. I can just use a FileConnection to write it -

```
        FileConnection filecon = (FileConnection)
                 Connector.open("file:///E:/imagefile.jpg");
        if (!filecon.exists())
            filecon.create(); // create the file if it doesn't exist
        DataOutputStream os = filecon.openDataOutputStream();
        os.write(raw);  // Raw image
```